# Trouble installing Indigo on Debian jessie (collada_parser build failure)

Tags: ros, debian, jessie

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following the directions at http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Debian (yes I realize this is fro Wheezy, but stick with me), everything seems to be OK up until the point at which I try and compile the packages with

```
sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/indigo
```

Building collada_parser fails:

```
==> make -j4 -l4 in '/home/laughlin/catkin_ws/build_isolated/collada_parser'
Scanning dependencies of target collada_parser
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/collada_parser.dir/src/collada_parser.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library /home/laughlin/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/collada_parser/lib/libcollada_parser.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcollada-dom2.4-dp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/collada_parser.dir/build.make:125: recipe for target '/home/laughlin/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/collada_parser/lib/libcollada_parser.so' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/laughlin/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/collada_parser/lib/libcollada_parser.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:122: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/collada_parser.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/collada_parser.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'collada_parser': 
  Command '['/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh', 'make', '-j4', '-l4']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/laughlin/catkin_ws/build_isolated/collada_parser && /opt/ros/indigo/env.sh make -j4 -l4
```

Doing a locate collada-dom2.4-dp I receive the following

```
/home/laughlin/catkin_ws/external_src/collada-dom-2.4.0/dom/libcollada-dom2.4-dp.so
/home/laughlin/catkin_ws/external_src/collada-dom-2.4.0/dom/libcollada-dom2.4-dp.so.0
/home/laughlin/catkin_ws/external_src/collada-dom-2.4.0/dom/libcollada-dom2.4-dp.so.2.4.0
/usr/local/lib/libcollada-dom2.4-dp.so.2.4.0
```

Because I'm new to CMake, and building anything of significance from source, I'm not sure where to even start on remedying this. I'm guessing it's looking for the file in /usr/local/lib, but can't find it, but I'm not sure.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226253/trouble-installing-indigo-on-debian-jessie-(collada_parser-build-failure)/) by [Laughlin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25908/laughlin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2016-02-10

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2016-02-10**:
Can you post the output of the following to a [gist](http://gist.github.com):

```
VERBOSE=1 cd /home/laughlin/catkin_ws/build_isolated/collada_parser && /opt/ros/indigo/env.sh make -j4 -l4
```

**Comment by [Laughlin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25908/laughlin/) on 2016-02-10**:
Here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b6f4d580d211b4b2b66c

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2016-02-10**:
Sorry, try:

```
export VERBOSE=1 && cd /home/laughlin/catkin_ws/build_isolated/collada_parser && /opt/ros/indigo/env.sh make -j4 -l4
```

**Comment by [Laughlin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25908/laughlin/) on 2016-02-10**:
Updated (thank you @jbohren!): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4ca0e1bbe2c66479dafc#file-stdout-txt-L18

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2016-02-10**:
After running checkinstall for collada you need to run ldconfig. Check if /usr/local/lib/libcollada-dom2.4-dp.so turns up in ldconfig -v and try again.

**Comment by [Laughlin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25908/laughlin/) on 2016-02-10**:
Success! Thank you @Humpelstilzchen.

**Comment by [anosseir](https://answers.ros.org/users/28076/anosseir/) on 2016-09-26**:
Hi all, I am still Stuck with the same error mentioned in this question (collada parser fails).
can you plz help me with detailed solution

- ( where/how exactly to run sudo ldconfig -v)
- when i check the above mention destination, i find (libcollada-dom2.4-dp.so.2.4.0)
- please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following advice from @Humpelstilzchen I got collada_parser built, and ROS installed. Removed  collada-com-dev (using dpkg worked fine), re-ran checkinstall, followed by

sudo ldconfig -v
(libcollada-dom2.4... did show up there)

ROS built cleanly and installed into appropriate directory thereafter.

Thanks for the help @jbohren and @Humpelstilzchen

---

Originally posted by [Laughlin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25908/laughlin/) with karma: 66 on 2016-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pratik Somaiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/27312/pratik-somaiya/) on 2016-07-04**:
Worked for me!! Thanks all of you :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@anosseir I had a similar problem. Even though catkin_make threw the same error than above, the problem seemed to be situated in the before compiled and installed urdf* packages. The following resolved for me the issue:

- I removed the self compiled packages

> ```
> sudo apt-get purge liburdfdom-headers-dev liburdfdom-dev
> ```

- And installed the binary packages from the debian Jessie repo (yes no need to compile):

> ```
> sudo apt-get install liburdfdom-dev liburdfdom-headers-dev
> ```

- check if the following packages are installed:

> ```
> sudo apt-get install liburiparser-dev libminizip-dev libboost-dev libpcre3-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-filesystem-dev
> ```

- recompile and checkinstall as before mentioned and described the collada-dom library
- run again

> ```
> rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y -r --os=debian:jessie
> ```

- continue the build

> ```
> sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/indigo
> ```

---

Originally posted by [tomtana](https://answers.ros.org/users/25903/tomtana/) with karma: 36 on 2017-01-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1